# How can the parent div auto resize its height based on the child's height?

Tags: html, css

How can the parent div auto resize it's height based on the child's height?

```css
div#main{
    width: 970px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    border: 5px solid rgb(251,151,117);
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px; /* Top Right Bottom Left*/
    padding: 10px       
}
div#left{width: 383px;
    height: 100%; 
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: rgb(0,0,255);
    float:left
}
div#description{width: 100%; 
    height: 50%; 
    background: rgb(0,0,0)  
}
div#following{width: 100%; 
    height: 50%; 
    background: rgb(0,255,0)  
}
div#posts{width: 577px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: rgb(255,255,0);
    float: right
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="left" class="cell">

        <div id="description" class="cell">
        </div>

        <div id="following" class="cell">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="posts" class="cell"> 
      there are some contents here (height is set to auto)
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just looking at those scrollbars on the code blocks after editing makes me sick inside.

Comment: @Joseph: What's your problem? You posted a ton of code with a title. Descriptions are gold man!

Comment: Now you reduced it too much, we'd like to see the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Don't set a height on the parent element? ;P

Comment: @Danjah - Oh! It didn't work xD

Comment: True.  What is the question here?

Comment: How can the height of the child element (which is set to auto) affect the height of the parent element? Or like inherit? LOL

Comment: look at this for deeper unterstanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a [*very simple* example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/STSjm/) for you to see how variable parent height works.

```css
.parent
{
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    padding: 5px;
}

.child
{
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Follow what is there and you'll do fine.

---

After looking through your code it's a float problem, you have to add a new div to the bottom with `clear: both;` to clear the floats and make the `#main`  div appear filled in.

[Look at example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/uGNXc/).

Comment: I know that. What bothers me is that there is , for example based on my question, another DIV like this :                                 <div><div><div></div><div></div> except that the last div is not a div (which has irregular heights so I have set the 2nd div, which contains the irregular-in-height content, to auto)

Comment: Like what? You're being far too vague.

Comment: Both of the links are broken. Would you mind recreating the examples and embed it in the post?

Answer (score 1):

```
div#main{
         width: 970px;

         background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
         border: 5px solid rgb(251,151,117);
         margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px; /* Top Right Bottom Left*/
         padding: 10px       
    }
```

Remove height attribute

Answer (score 0):

CSS3

```
.container {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
```

Should fix it. Use `inline-block` if you want it to be a block with inline.